# If $T$ is a operator linear such that ||T||>0 then $T$ is one-to-one

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X \longrightarrow X$ a linear operator, where $X$ is a Banach Space. If $$||T||>0$$ then $T$ is one-to-one.
Is this statement true? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: I don’t think so. Every non zero operator has norm non zero... not every non zero operator is injective. You can actually pick one non injective operator and show that its norm is non zero. I don’t think Banach space has anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is *very* non true: in the sense that $\|T\|>0$ for any $T$ other than the zero operator.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ &0\end{bmatrix}$ is a linear operator $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that has operator norm $1$, but is not one-to-one.